# Using List in GQL Filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

How can I make a selection in GQL using a List as filter.

If I have the class

```
public class Obj{

    @Persistent
    private Long name;

}
```

How can I get all Obj's that the name **are not in** a list?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

Comment: Thanks @lucemia, but I have alread read it and this tutorial doesn't help me. :(

Comment: OK, btw, what do you mean "using a list as a filter"? You want to filter an entity by its ListProperty? or you want to use a list as the condition?

Comment: I make some edition on the question to clarify it?

Comment: What percentage of results will you be filtering out by excluding certain names? It may be more efficient to simply retrieve all the results and exclude the ones you don't want after retrieving them.

Comment: It will be excluded less than 1%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results by chain all filters together.

```
SELECT * FROM User where email != 'xxx@gmail.com' and email != 'yyy@gmail.com' and email != 'zzz@gmail.com'
```

Python Code

```
q = User.all()
for i in ilist:
    q = q.filter("email = ", i)
```

But you may need to know there are some limitations for this kind of query.

> Note: The IN and != operators use multiple queries behind the scenes. For example, the IN operator executes a separate underlying datastore query for every item in the list. The entities returned are a result of the cross-product of all the underlying datastore queries and are de-duplicated. A maximum of 30 datastore queries are allowed for any single GQL query.

Comment: And how about threat that like a list. I'm already using this solution, but I want to know howto filter using a list of values.

Comment: You can get objs in the list by the "in" condition. However, I don't think there is a way to get objs not in the list directly.